# WPF: Why are nested styles not always working?

Tags: wpf, styles, nested, toolbar, togglebutton

I'm trying to apply a nested WPF style to a Toolbar. I'd like to have all children of the Toolbar (MenuItems, Buttons, ToggleButtons etc.) to have the specified style.

**The problem is, that the nested style definition is applied correctly to some controls like MenuItems, but not to Buttons. 
What am I doing wrong?**

The MenuItem is correctly placed at the bottom of the Toolbar, but the ToggleButton is in the middle:

[image: This is what it looks like]

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyToolbarStyle" TargetType="ToolBar">
        <!-- Setters for Toolbar properties -->
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="80" />

        <!-- Nested setters for children of the Toolbar -->
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom" />
            </Style>

            <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom" />
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>

    </Style>
</Window.Resources>


<Grid >
    <ToolBar VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource MyToolbarStyle}">
        <MenuItem Header="MyMenuItem"  />           <!-- Appears on the bottom like defined in the style-->
        <ToggleButton Content="MyToggleButton" />   <!-- Nested style does not seem to be applied-->
    </ToolBar>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WPF `ToolBar` is a special type of control that defines some custom styles for some WPF controls like `Button`, `ToggleButton`... full list [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.toolbar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you can identify them by `ElementName + StyleKey` property name. If you'd like to change a default style for a specific control you will have to modify one of these styles.

Try replacing your style for the `ToggleButton` with the following:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Static ToolBar.ToggleButtonStyleKey}" TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong is *thinking that WPF `Style`s are like `CSS` styles*. In WPF, `Style`s are just not used that way. Sure, if we could, we'd probably save a few lines of XAML, but we can't. The best that we can do is what you have done... I'm assuming that you've created a `Style` for a top level element like `Control`. As you have seen, not all controls will extend the `Control` class, so the `Style` won't be applied to all of them.

Instead, `Style`s in WPF are more like the `.class` styles in CSS... one `Style` per type and then we can apply a further `Style` per UI element. There are lots of situations like this in WPF where we wish we could write less code, but it is how it is and the sooner that everybody realises it, the better.

---

UPDATE >>>

In response to your first comment, you seem to be mistaken. Just to clarify, if what you are calling *nested `Style`s* are the `Style`s that you defined in the outer `Style.Resources` section, then there is nothing wrong with that... no problem what-so-ever. Just take those inner `Style`s out of the `Resources` section and you will see the same UI.

Now you're probably thinking of changing your question title to something like 'Why isn't my default `ToggleButton Style` being applied inside a `ToolBar` control?'. While I can't say for sure, I can only assume that this behaviour is caused by a `Style` that has been defined within the `ToolBar ControlTemplate`.

I'm thinking that because of the following points:

- A custom implicit `Style` (no x:Key) will not work inside the `ToolBar` control.
- A custom explicit `Style` (named) *will* work as expected inside the `ToolBar` control.
- A `Style` property set on the element *will* work as expected inside the `ToolBar` control.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your answer: MenuItem is a Control and ToggelButton is a Control as well. There might be advantages and disadvantages of nested styles, but why isn't it working in my example.